# Best iptables configuration for a xenserver with management interface exposed to www

Tags: iptables, xenserver

Which is the best iptables configuration to protect a management interface of a xenserver with management interface exposed to www?

This is my actual configuration:

```
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> :RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
> -A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
> -A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -p 50 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -p 51 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -s MY-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -s MY-SECOND-FIXED-IP-ADDRESS -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the best? Do not make it available. Period.

Configure a VPN and then require that people connect to the VPN first, before being able to access the management interface.

Comment: I know, but this question is about a server that can't have a dedicated hardware firewall. Thanks.